# Different Pro Tools errors - and what do they actually mean?

Tags: pro-tools, problems, error, unexpected-error

I´ve recently encountered many different kind of Pro Tools errors and it really annoys me that the error messages themselves don´t give a whole lot of information what´s wrong in Pro Tools. It would be nice if you could explain me what the common "Dae error 35" means in Pro Tools since it keeps popping up every now and then and crashes Pro Tools. Are there many of these error messages in Pro Tools and what do they mean?

Comment: I've learned nothing at all about the problem. I've transferred my protools files to a hard drive, tried to run/open it through my hard drive, but the DAE 35 error keeps coming up. I end up transferring my transferred files from my Mac, to my hard drive, back onto my mac (or another mac) in order for it to work again

Answer (score 5):

http://www.mixcoach.com/common-dae-errors-and-their-causes/

Official FAQ about troubleshooting DAE Errors:
http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/FAQ/en363439

Answer (score 3):

This refers to a drive error...

Make sure that you are not using a USB hard drive and that you're internal HD runs at 7200rpm.

If you're internal drive is fast enough and you are not using a USB external, maybe try and repair disk permissions in disk utilities if you're using a Mac, not too sure how you do that on a PC.

There are also other errors and normally you can find out enough information to troubleshoot i the Avid forums. http://duc.avid.com/index.php